# TikTok's in-app browser not loading html/css code for videos

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser, in-app

I currently have this html code:

```
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay loop="" preload="auto" muted poster="" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="my video url" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This code works perfectly on every browser including for mobile. It even works for in Instagram's own in-app web browser when you tap on a link/open something in their app. However this doesn't work for TikTok's own in-app web browser. Didn't find much resources on this especially debugging in-app web browsers so any help is much appreciated!

Don't think this is needed but here is my css code as well:

```
.fullscreen-bg__video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;

}
/* new div */
.cover {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: u can try this code. hope i helped.  

<video controls playsinline="playsinline" autoplay loop="" preload="auto" muted poster=""
        class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type=video/mp4>
    </video>

and the style stays

or you can study more on w3schools website to learn more on html

Comment: @xAtifx thanks for the help but I tried your code and it still doesn't work for tiktok :( The video on instagram's in app browser loads in but the one on TikTok doesn't despite the video controls showing (they only show that the video is 0 seconds long when it is actually 5)

Comment: Any updates folks?

Comment: @Johnfabric No update yet. Through more debugging it seems that TikTok's browser most likely doesn't support 'playsinline'. A work around I am currently using is just displaying the first frame of the video (better than nothing). Let me know if you reach any solutions!

Comment: @watchnlearn how are you able to display the first frame of the video? I am in a place where the first frame doesn't show up for me at all, thereby showing a blank video